# How to run windows installation of PostgreSQL on wsl?

Tags: postgresql, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So I'm trying to get PostgreSQL to work on my windows device. I installed it through wsl and it all works, but I hear its safer to do the windows install and run it through wsl. How do I do this? What port do i give to the windows installation of PostgreSQL? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but what exactly is the difference. Doing this for a uni course I just started.

Comment: The complete then. How would I go about that, and is installing through windows actually better then through wsl?

Comment: The port of the Windows installation should be the standard just connect to this port from your wsl program it should work. Make sure that you have un installed Postgres from wsl first.